# Accessing siblings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access the sibling of a column :

```
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
```

When i click over 3, how can i access 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
$('td:last').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('td:first').css('color', 'red');
})
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/RK56q/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.siblings` jquery function

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood;

```
var td = $('tr td'), len = td.length;
td.on('click', function() {
    var i = (td.index(this) + 1) % len;
    console.log(td.eq(i));
});
```

this will return

- 2nd `td` when you click on 1st `td`
- 3rd `td` when you click on 2nd `td`
- 1st `td` when you click on 3rd `td`

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BmYue/2/

Answer (score 0):

or you could use .parent() and .children() method as well to access it.

```
$(this).parent().children()
```

But easier version is .siblings jquery function.

http://api.jquery.com/parent/
http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: $(this).parent().siblings(":first").html()  i tried this , but not working

Comment: when you refer $(this) it refers to td element so try this.

 you could access directly as $(this).siblings(":first").html() or else use $(this).parent().children(":first").html()

Comment: This won't help with your main problem, but I notices that you don't need the first selector because .html() only returns the value for the first element in a list